# docusign connector dynamics 2013

Tags: dynamics-crm-2013, docusignapi

I noticed the docusign connector is documented to be compatible with Dynamics CRM 2011 only.  Is this a failure to update the documentation or does it not work with Dynamics CRM 2013?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple Google search for "DocuSign Dynamics CRM" gives you links about **DocuSign for Microsoft Dynamics CRM 2013**:

- http://www.docusign.com/partner/docusign-for-microsoft-dynamics-crm-2013
- https://www.docusign.com/sites/default/files/Integrations/DynamicsCRM/DocuSign_for_Microsoft_Dynamics_CRM_2013.pdf
- https://www.docusign.com/sites/default/files/DocuSign%20for%20Dynamics%202013%20QS%20Guide.pdf